# What is the purpose of Android Room version code

Tags: android, android-room

I'm using a Room database with the following Database declaration:

```
@androidx.room.Database(entities =
        {DatabaseEntities.Session.class,
                DatabaseEntities.Activity.class,
                DatabaseEntities.AirplaneMode.class,
                DatabaseEntities.BatteryState.class,
        }, version = 2, exportSchema = false)
```

In my database I don't see the version declared above. What is the purpose of the version code and how can I see it in the database?

Comment: If you make changs to the database structure, you must increment that number in order to `onUpgrade` method get called. In that method, you must write proper SQL statements to perform those database changes.

Comment: Version number triggers schema regeneration and is used for DB migration, as explained in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version number is used by Room to determine when it needs to generate a new schema and for [database migration](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions).

The version number is stored in the database and can be obtained as shown below. `db` is an instance of a [RoomDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase).

Java:

```
int version = db.getOpenHelper().getReadableDatabase().getVersion();
```

Kotlin:

```
val version = db.openHelper.readableDatabase.version
```